# materialize css modal not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I'm working with Materialize CSS and using the collapsible accordion-style element ( http://materializecss.com/collapsible.html).

For some reason, I wasn't able to choose anything after the 5th option.
[Here is the picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaTpG.jpg) I don't know why I can't select anything after the fifth option (Terrengan u).

When Kelantan is being clicked, the value of the previous selected is not updated to it, while anything above Kelantan works.

Here is my code. My goal is simply to be able to use collapsible as intended (i.e. with the element opening and remaining open).

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="input-field col s4 m6 l12">
        <select class="icons">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your state</option>
            <option value="" data-icon="images/flag/perlis.jpg" class="left circle responsive-img">Perlis</option>
            <option value="" data-icon="images/flag/kedah.jpg" class="left circle responsive-img">Kedah</option>
            <option value="" data-icon="images/flag/penang.jpg" class="left circle responsive-img">Pulau Pinang</option>
            <option value="" data-icon="images/flag/perak.jpg" class="left circle responsive-img">Perak</option>
            <option value="" data-icon="images/flag/terrenganu.jpg" class="left circle responsive-img">Terenggan    u</option>
            <option value="" data-icon="images/flag/kelantan.jpg" class="left circle responsive-img">Kelantan</option>
            <option value="" data-icon="images/flag/pahang.jpg" class="left circle">Pahang</option>
            <option value="" data-icon="images/flag/selangor.jpg" class="left circle">Selangor</option>
            <option value="" data-icon="images/flag/sembilan.jpg" class="left circle">Sembilan</option>
            <option value="" data-icon="images/flag/malacca.jpg" class="left circle">Malaka</option>
            <option value="" data-icon="images/flag/johor.jpg" class="left circle">Johor</option>
            <option value="" data-icon="images/flag/sarawak.jpg" class="left circle">Sarawak</option>
            <option value="" data-icon="images/flag/sabah.jpg" class="left circle">Sabah</option>
        </select>
        <label>Select State</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('select').material_select();
    });
</script>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8rmjymtr/5/

I've found another post with the same problem too. https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/2436

Comment: So um... where's your collapsible? What does it have to do with this select box?

Comment: Sorry my bad. It was inside the modal not callapsible

Comment: If you can reproduce your problem on jsfiddle or something, so people can tinker around with it, it would be better. The html you pasted in is perfectly normal and doesn't tell much about the problem. The unintended behavior is most likely because of other parts of the document.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm currently reproduce my problem on jsfiddle. Will get back to you.

Comment: Hi. Here is the link for jsfiddle. Thank you
http://jsfiddle.net/8rmjymtr/5/

Comment: Interesting. I'll just report what I have found here: the bug is not related to the index of the selected option, but occur when you scroll the list. So as long as you don't scroll it'll be fine. Looking for a way to fix this. Seems like a bug with the library itself...

Comment: Ok I can confirm it is a library's issue. Was able to reproduce the bug on the library's website itself. You can report the bug to the developer: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues. Unfortunately I don't have enough tool to delve deeper on this laptop.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'll report the bug to the developer. Thank you

Comment: Since this comment solved the question, wouldn't it be best to repeat it again as an answer so it won't show up as unsolved anymore?

Comment: I just had a look at the JSFiddle. For me, it works fine - I am able to click every single item in the dropdown menu, along with selecting it, clicking away from the modal, clicking on the button to show it again with it still being there. What is it you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked out the fiddle .It seems to me that the issue is with the select box . If you change or add select box class to browser-default. The fiddle works fine .

```
 <select class="icons browser-default"> // this line
```

The issue is with the select box options are not getting registered with the DOM when the modal height exceeds the height of parent element,thus causing the options which are not rendered initially to not be selectable...
so even if we click on the options the click is not registered and option is not selected.

To fix this you can use a [drop-down](http://materializecss.com/dropdown.html) instead of select box or go ahead with browser-default select box if that is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug in Materialize v0.97.3 .
Here is a fiddle with Materialize v0.97.5 .

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="input-field col s4 m6 l12">
        <select class="icons">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your state</option>
            <option value="" data-icon="images/flag/perlis.jpg" class="left circle responsive-img">Perlis</option>
            <option value="" data-icon="images/flag/kedah.jpg" class="left circle responsive-img">Kedah</option>
            <option value="" data-icon="images/flag/penang.jpg" class="left circle responsive-img">Pulau Pinang</option>
            <option value="" data-icon="images/flag/perak.jpg" class="left circle responsive-img">Perak</option>
            <option value="" data-icon="images/flag/terrenganu.jpg" class="left circle responsive-img">Terenggan    u</option>
            <option value="" data-icon="images/flag/kelantan.jpg" class="left circle responsive-img">Kelantan</option>
            <option value="" data-icon="images/flag/pahang.jpg" class="left circle">Pahang</option>
            <option value="" data-icon="images/flag/selangor.jpg" class="left circle">Selangor</option>
            <option value="" data-icon="images/flag/sembilan.jpg" class="left circle">Sembilan</option>
            <option value="" data-icon="images/flag/malacca.jpg" class="left circle">Malaka</option>
            <option value="" data-icon="images/flag/johor.jpg" class="left circle">Johor</option>
            <option value="" data-icon="images/flag/sarawak.jpg" class="left circle">Sarawak</option>
            <option value="" data-icon="images/flag/sabah.jpg" class="left circle">Sabah</option>
        </select>
        <label>Select State</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('select').material_select();
    });
</script>
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8rmjymtr/9/

Works fine with updated materialize version. Tested locally with Materialize v0.97.5 on Chrome latest.